# CursorWindow number of columns

Tags: android, cursor

How can I know how many columns there are on a `CursorWindow`?
Why it has a `getNumRows()` but no `getNumColumns()`, despite having a `setNumColumns()`?

Comment: Why "in the name of God" are you dealing with a `CursorWindow` yourself in the first place?

Comment: [Too long to explain here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790893/passing-a-cursor-between-processes-parcelable-cursor) TLDR: because it's the only `Cursor`-thingy that implements `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it in this **most horrible** way:

```
/**
 * Get the number of columns of this CursorWindow. The CursorWindow has to
 * have at least one row.
 */
public static int getCursorWindowNumCols(CursorWindow window) {

    // Ugly hack...
    int j = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            window.getString(0, j);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            break;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // It's a BLOB!
        }
        j++;
    }
    return j;
}
```

I **don't recommend** using this. Just posting it if someone has the same problem and needs a quick solution to get moving.