# Send a cursor to an activity from a service

Tags: android, cursor, parcelable, intentservice

I'm trying to send database cursor from a service(An IntentService) to my Activity(Which implements a Receiver to catch any response from the service). Once i get the data from query `cursor = db.query(DBHelper.DB_BOOKS_TABLE, columns, where, whereArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);` i would like to send back the cursor from the service to his caller thru the receiver. but the bundle structure just let me send tical data(Strings, ints, thinks like that). i know the bundle also let send parcelable objects and Serializable Objects. but how do i convert a typical cursor to a parcelable or serializable cursor. thks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opt for made my own custom class which implements a **Parcelable Interface**. since the parcelable cursors like [CrossProcessCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CrossProcessCursor.html) is quite unknown for me.

Inside of my own ParcelableRow i just implement **HashMap** object. To don't worry anymore about amount of rows or columns, I just map the cursor to my *own ParcelableRow object*. here is mi code:

```
public class ParcelableRow implements Parcelable {
 private HashMap<String, String> colsMap;


 public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableRow> CREATOR
 = new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableRow>() {

    @Override
    public ParcelableRow createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new ParcelableRow(source);
    }

    @Override
    public ParcelableRow[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ParcelableRow[size];
    }
};


public ParcelableRow(Parcel in) {
    colsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    readFromParcel(in);
}
public ParcelableRow() {
    colsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    for(String key: colsMap.keySet()){

        dest.writeString(key);
        dest.writeString(colsMap.get(key));

    }

}
public void readFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {

    int limit = parcel.dataSize();
    parcel.setDataPosition(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        colsMap.put(parcel.readString(), parcel.readString());
    }

}


public void addNewCol(String colName, String colValue){
    colsMap.put(colName, colValue);
}
public String getColumnValue(String colName){
    return colsMap.get(colName);
}
```

}
Thanks to @CommonsWare to gave me a clue. thumbs up!.

I hope this can be useful to someone, i've just spend some days trying to find something that could satisfy my needs. [here](http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/10/28/writing-parcelable-classes-for-android/) are some code examples which i've used. advises are welcome.

**Warning** It only satisfy me because i'm against the time.

keep coding!

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use a `Bundle` to send anything from the `Service` to the `Activity`. You can do it like this in the `Service`. I am talking strictly about a `Service` here and not an `IntentService`, as I've not used them before. Using a bound `Service` is the same, but just call `unbindService()` in your Activity when you're done with it:

```
private Cursor cursor;
public void initializeCursor() {
    cursor = Cursor();
    //Now the cursor is created. Send a broadcast to the activity that it's done.
    broadcastManager.sendBroadcast("your.package.CURSOR_FINISHED");
}
```

and have a `getCursor()` method for the `Activity`:

```
public Cursor getCursor() {
    return this.cursor;
}
```

And in the `BroadcastReceiver` of your `Activity`, catch this event:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("your.package.CURSOR_FINISHED") {
        Cursor cursor = myService.getCursor();
        unbindService(myServiceConnection);
    }
}
```

As your activity is bound to your service, you will have a service object avaiable in your activity. Once you get the broadcast that the cursor is done, just kill the service.